# Is it possible to add custom autonumbering lists in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

InDesign CC comes with a set of pre-defined autonumbering lists:

1. 2. 3. 

a. b. c.

0001, 0002, 0003.... etc.

Is there a way to add a custom autonumbering list such as Cyrillic letters or custom numbering such as 000001?
InDesign MiddleEastern version does add Hebrew and Arabic numbering systems and Japanese version adds Chinese and Japanese numbering systems but nothing is customizable.
For that matter InDesign's Object Reference only mentions the lists I mention above.
Any answers to that?

Comment: In the Paragraph Window, go to Bullets and Numbering. Note that this question is more suitable for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ as it does not concern itself with programming

Comment: Thank you. Posted there as well. Handling the problem might require scripting or a plugin, not only being able to handle out-of-the-box InDesign.

Comment: As a funny clumsy workaround: you can make a font with Cyrillic letters instead of Latin ones (A-->A, B-->Б, C-->В, D--Г) and use this messy font as a 'numbers' for lists. It should be enough for the first 26 elements of a list. Of course if you don't mind to convert the list into a plain text you can do such replacements with a script. The task is quite trivial.